# Wait for a task to finish on other view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, xcode, uiview

I'm developing an application where user needs to login first. It is actually a tabBar Application and I have loader a login view over it in the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions` method. This what i have done:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES animated:NO];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    authView = [[AuthViewController alloc] init];
    // Add the tab bar controller's view to the window and display.
    [window addSubview:tabBarController.view];
    [UIView beginAnimations:@"curldown" context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
    [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlDown forView:authView.view cache:YES];
    [window addSubview:authView.view];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
    [window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;

    [authView release];
}
```

What I want is First View controller to wait until this login view is removed. For more details, this how I removed the authView in authViewController:

```
[UIView beginAnimations:@"curlup" context:nil];
        [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
        [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlUp forView:self.view.superview cache:YES];          
        [self.view removeFromSuperview];
        [UIView commitAnimations];
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [NSNotification](http://iphonedevelopertips.com/cocoa/basics-of-notifications.html).

All the best.

Comment: Hi can you show me how can I achieve that using NSNotification? I tried myself but couldn't get success. :(

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to set up the delegate hierarchy? That might be helpful since what you actually need is communication between different controllers.